# Does get request need content type and accept header?

Tags: asp.net

I am making web request and method is get.Does I need to mention content-Type and accept for get method?or it just require for post method

```
string strURL = "web address";
        Uri uri = new Uri(strURL);

 HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;   

          webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
          webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
          webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```

Comment: are you want to call a get method ?

Comment: no need to put Accept and Contenttype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**content-type** : It is not required in the GET request as you are not sending any content in the request body.

> content-type indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient.

**Accept** : It depends on your requirement. If you want to restrict the media type in your response then you can use it otherwise leave it.

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.